# how to check if password expiry column in a store procedure has only 14,7,3,2,1 days left?

Tags: sql-server

> i have an sp that i check if user's password change date has 14 days
>   left(`flag=0)` and i send email to that users and i that sp i check(by a
>   col.flag) if email already sent or not.after that i update the the
>   flag col.in an another SP(`ExpiryNotificationFlag`) to 1 of users list whose email has
>   already sent..now i don't know how to check for 7,3,2,1 days as flag
>   col value is already 1 ?

**sp**

```
        SELECT  TenantName
              , TenantEmail 
              , GMAP_code
              , ContactID       FROM (
                SELECT    b_1.TenantName
                        , b_1.TenantEmail
                        , LastPDWChangeDate =(SELECT ISNULL(max (DateChanged),GETDATE()) FROM dbo.wsm_Contact_PwdHistory WHERE ContactID = b_1.TenantRegContactID)
                        , ExpiryNotificationFlag =(SELECT top 1 ExpiryNotificationFlag FROM dbo.wsm_Contact_PwdHistory WHERE ContactID = b_1.TenantRegContactID order by DateChanged desc)
                        , GMAP_code =(SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(GMAP_CODE,'') from wsm_Ref_Buildings where BuildingId = b_1.BuildingID)
                        , b_1.TenantRegContactID as ContactID
                FROM     dbo.wsm_Contact AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN  
                (
                    SELECT C.Name AS TenantName
                        , A.SiteID
                        , A.BuildingID
                        , A.FloorID
                        , A.ContactID AS TenantRegContactID
                        , D.LEASID
                        , C.Phone AS TenantPhone
                        , C.Email AS TenantEmail
                        , B.UserID AS userid
                        , C.Mobile AS TenantMobile 
                        , B.UserType 
                    FROM  dbo.wsm_Contact_Tenancy AS A 
                    INNER JOIN  dbo.wsm_Contact_User AS B ON A.ContactID = B.ContactID AND B.Active = 1  
                    INNER JOIN  dbo.wsm_Contact AS C ON B.ContactID = C.ContactID 
                    INNER JOIN  (
                            SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE (LEASID, ExtLeasNum) AS LEASID
                                , SiteID
                                , BuildingID
                                , FloorID  
                            FROM  dbo.wsm_Contact) AS D ON A.SiteID = D.SiteID AND A.BuildingID = D.BuildingID AND A.FloorID = D.FloorID) AS b_1 ON   
                                COALESCE (a.LEASID, a.ExtLeasNum) = b_1.LEASID AND a.SiteID = b_1.SiteID AND a.BuildingID = b_1.BuildingID AND a.FloorID = b_1.FloorID 
                            INNER JOIN  dbo.wsm_Ref_Floors AS C ON a.FloorID = C.FloorId  
                            WHERE (a.OCCPSTAT NOT IN ('I', 'P')) and C.Deleted = 0 and b_1.userid is not null       ) AS A WHERE   DATEDIFF(DAY,A.LastPDWChangeDate,getdate()) = 76 AND ISNULL(ExpiryNotificationFlag,0) <> 1

END
```

**update Query**

```
 UPDATE dbo.wsm_Contact_PwdHistory  set ExpiryNotificationFlag = 1 WHERE ContactID = @ContactID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like that

```
( (DATEDIFF(DAY,A.LastPDWChangeDate,getdate()) = 76 AND ISNULL(ExpiryNotificationFlag,0) = 0)  --14 days      

  or (DATEDIFF(DAY,A.LastPDWChangeDate,getdate()) = 83 AND ISNULL(ExpiryNotificationFlag,0) = 1) --7days      

  or (DATEDIFF(DAY,A.LastPDWChangeDate,getdate()) = 87 AND ISNULL(ExpiryNotificationFlag,0) = 2) --3 days      

  or (DATEDIFF(DAY,A.LastPDWChangeDate,getdate()) = 88 AND ISNULL(ExpiryNotificationFlag,0) = 3) --2 days      
  or (DATEDIFF(DAY,A.LastPDWChangeDate,getdate()) = 89 AND ISNULL(ExpiryNotificationFlag,0) = 4) --1 day      

  )
```

**for that u have to modify Expiry notification flag to int instead of a Boolean

after that make a SP where will u update the value from 
0 to 1,1 to 2,2 to 3 etc.**

Answer (score 0):

Youre essentially making the following complaint:

> "A boolean datatype can only store one of two values!"

Indeed, so swap out that flag for a "Number of Days Left" column, and compare it to 14, 7, whatever....

Note, ExpiryNotificationFlag column isn't a great name - how about "PasswordExpiryEmailSent"

Sometimes these problems get a lot easier to think about when the columns have better names